# Different kinds of derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So we define the derivative as the linear map satisfying $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{||f(p+h)-f(p)-L(h)||}{||h||}=0$. My intuition for the derivative is that it is the best function in the class of linear functions that approximates f.
I was wondering if my intuition makes sense, and if so what about other classes of functions.
It seems that we have an answer for quadratic, cubic etc. via Taylor series.
What about the class of exponential functions E? What sort of requirements would we impose on $||f(p+h)-f(p)-E(h)||$?

Comment: This is roughly right but one has to understand "best" in a specific sense, which is local to the point $p$. One could ask for global best approximations and these will give different approximations, not the Taylor polynomials. For exponential functions you can take the logarithm of $f$ and consider linear approximations to this.